# Vert.x future handler setting

Tags: java, vert.x

Please have a look on following piece of code located inside class extending `AbstractVerticle`:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> serverStartFuture) throws Exception {

    log.info("Deploying " + this.getClass().toString() + " verticle...");

    //TODO: Handler is not calling.
    serverStartFuture.setHandler(event -> {
        if(event.succeeded()){
            log.info("Deploying " + this.getClass().toString() + " verticle SUCCESS");
        } else if (event.failed()){
            log.error("Deploying " + this.getClass().toString() + " verticle FAIL:");
            log.error(event.cause());
        }
    });

    /* To follow future compose pattern in future */
    Future<Void> initSteps = this.initHttpServ();
    initSteps.setHandler((AsyncResult<Void> asyncResult) -> {
        if(asyncResult.succeeded()){
            serverStartFuture.complete();
        }else if(asyncResult.failed()){
            serverStartFuture.fail(asyncResult.cause());
        }
    });

}
```

Assuming that `initHttpServ` always return complete future:

```
private Future<Void> initHttpServ(){
    Future<Void> httpServerFuture = Future.future();
    httpServerFuture.complete();
    return  httpServerFuture;
}
```

Why the `serverStartFuture.setHandler` is never called in my case?
I understand the concept that way:

- Create future `f`
- set `f` future handler
- forget about it
- Somewhere else in code set `f` to `complete`/`fail`
- After setting `f` result, handler will call

But my piece of code seems to negate this approach.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see "INFO: Deploying class [classname] verticle SUCCESS" in the logs. Can you show what appears in the logs for you and what you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to set the `serverStartFuture` handler. It is set by Vert.x when the verticle is deployed. You're supposed to either complete the future when your verticle starts successfully, or fail otherwise.

See [Asynchronous Verticle start and stop](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_verticle_start_and_stop) in the Vert.x core documentation.

Comment: Oh I see, than I understand that `future` passed to start method is the only one that would not work this way.